# How to make Ubuntu 22.04 save screenshot as png and not just place it on clipboard?

Tags: 22.04, screenshot

Ubuntu 22.04 64-bit LTS
I was surprised to see the new screenshot tool throw up a message that I could paste the screenshot into a file. Why should this be required? My old 18.04 setup could do it out of the box. How do I configure this basic function? I could not find anything in settings.

Comment: Remain calm. If you play with it a bit more, you will discover that output is now both clipboard AND file. 22.04 does it out of the box, too, without any configuration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even if I liked the old gnome-screenshot tool, the new tool even improves.

If you just invoke it, <kbd>PrtScr</kbd>, you can still do everything: make screenshots of the entire screen, a window or selection, or record the screen. You do not need to think ahead on whether you want a screenshot to file, or one to the clipboard: the new tool just does both.

Make your screenshot, and find the file in `~/Pictures/Screenshots`, or paste it in your application. It is your choice.

If you know what you want to capture, then hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> to capture the entire screen, or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> to capture the active window. Again, no need to think ahead: paste the figure or find the file in `~/Pictures/Screenshots`: it is your choice.

So also in 22.04, both functions are available, but the mental overhead - do I want output in clipboard or in a file - has been removed.

Answer (score 5):

The screenshots should automatically be saved into ~/Pictures/Screenshots or the equivalent if you're using a different language. You can directly navigate to the folder from the message you see when taking a screenshot by hovering your mouse over the dialog.

[image: Screenshot of the "Screenshot captured" dialog].

Comment: If you disable notifications, you won't see the message (unless you manually check notifications), which can be unsettling
However the screenshot is indeed stored in the clipboard