# Screenshot saving

Tags: clipboard, screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g17DY.png)

In ubuntu 18.04 lts we have options like to save in pictures. If it's not required to save in pictures we have other option to set in keyboard screenshot. It will just keep in clipboard. Those options are unable in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

I don't wish to save in pictures folder. It must just keep in clipboard. Pls help how to set that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Screenshot selection in 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407422/screenshot-selection-in-22-04)

Answer (score 0):

The new tool saves [both to the clipboard and to a file](https://askubuntu.com/a/1411965/558158). That is not user configurable in the tool itself. The good thing of this change is that you do not need to think ahead before taking the screenshot on what output you want. You can focus solely on making a screenshot.

- If you do not want to keep the image files around, you can setup a cron job that deletes the files in `~/Pictures/Screenshots` at regular times.
- If you do not want to see the `~/Pictures/Screenshots` folder, you can hide it by creating a text file `~/Pictures/.hidden` that contains the name of the folder you want to hide.
- If all this bores you, you can instead revert back to the old screenshot tool. 1) Install `gnome-screenshot`, 2) disable any of the keybindings to take a screenshot in "Settings" - "Keyboard", "Screenshots" and 3) define your own shortcuts in the section "Custom Shortcuts" to reinstate the behavior of Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: thanks. 3rd one I like . Im out of my desktop now. I will check tomorrow morning and inform you .

Comment: what is the command for save a screenshot of an area to pictures and command for copy a screenshot to clipboard

Comment: Can anyone help with commands pls